# International Auto-login for Git Config

Tags: git

I am wondering if there's a way to enter the auto login credentials into the .git/config http line for windows domains. Apparently the backslash is a bad character for .git/config files.

```
Ex: http://country\my_username:mypassword@my_git_repo.git
```

Yes I know this isn't the best security practice but we are on an internal network behind firewalls and rules can be bent for our needs.

TIA,

Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Git documentation (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.8/git-config.html), backslashes have to be escaped as a double backslash: `\\`.

Ideally, you wouldn't put the password here, but use the Git credential helper to store the password instead.

Comment: Thanks. We ended up figuring a way around using the domain\ anyway since it's an internally hosted git server (Bonobo) and we really could do whatever we wanted.